# Hibernate faster EntityManagerFactory creation

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, orm

In my desktop application new databases get opened quite often. I use `Hibernate`/`JPA` as an ORM.
The problem is, creating the `EntityManagerFactory` is quite slow, taking about 5-6 Seconds on a fast machine. I know that the `EntityManagerFactory` is supposed to be heavyweight but this is just too slow for a desktop application where the user expects the new database to be opened quickly.

1. Can I turn off some EntityManagerFactory features to get an instance
   faster? Or is it possible to create some of the EntityManagerFactory lazily to speed up creation?
2. Can I somehow create the EntityManagerFactory object before
   knowing the database url? I would be happy to turn off all
   validation for this to be possible.
3. By doing so, can I pool EntityManagerFactorys for later use?
4. Any other idea how to create the EntityManagerFactory faster?

**Update with more Information and JProfiler profiling**

The desktop application can open saved files. Our application document file format consists of 1 SQLite database + and some binary data in a ZIP file. When opening a document, the ZIP gets extracted and the db is opened with Hibernate. The databases all have the same schema, but different data obviously.

It seems that the first time I open a file it takes significantly longer than the following times.
I profiled the first and second run with JProfiler and compared the results.

1st Run:

```
create EMF: 4385ms
    build EMF: 3090ms
    EJB3Configuration configure: 900ms
    EJB3Configuration <clinit>: 380ms
```

[image: calltree1.png].

2nd Run:

```
create EMF: 1275ms
    build EMF: 970ms
    EJB3Configuration configure: 305ms
    EJB3Configuration <clinit>: not visible, probably 0ms
```

[image: compare_calltree.png].

In the Call tree comparison you can see that some methods are significantly faster (DatabaseManager. as starting point):

```
create EMF: -3120ms
    Hibernate create EMF: -3110ms
        EJB3Configuration configure: -595ms
        EJB3Configuration <clinit>: -380ms
        build EMF: -2120ms
            buildSessionFactory: -1945ms
                secondPassCompile: -425ms
                buildSettings: -346ms
                SessionFactoryImpl.<init>: -1040ms
```

The Hot spot comparison now has the interesting results:

[image: screenshot compare_hotspot.png].

```
ClassLoader.loadClass: -1686ms
XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema: -184ms
ClassFile.<init>: -109ms
```

I am not sure if it is the loading of Hibernate classes or my Entity classes.

A first improvement would be to create an EMF as soon as the application starts just to initialize all necessary classes (I have an empty db file as a prototype already shipped with my Application). @sharakan thank you for your answer, maybe a DeferredConnectionProvider would already be a solution for this problem.

I will try the DeferredConnectionProvider next! But we might be able to speed it up even further. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: Are your database mappings in XML or annotations?

Comment: I have a `hibernate.cfg.xml` with mappings. The entitity classes are annotated.
Then when I know the databese url I also supply a properties string at EnitityManagerFactory creation. It is built like this:
`Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
 properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", JDBC.PREFIX + dbFile.getAbsolutePath());`
I am open to change this, if I speeds up the creation of EntityManagerFactory. Any suggestions?

Comment: in that case you'll get a performance improvement if you move away from annotations and _only_ use xml to define your mappings. Scanning classes and looking for annotations is slower than just reading xml

Comment: In this case, the platform is very important. Are you using Hibernate for a desktop application? Aren't you using a client-server architecture? If you do very often database opennings and closings, maybe a client-server application would satisfy your needs to overcome these delays.

Comment: Can you nail down what is done in these 5 seconds - connecting, reading database metadata, parsing class files, generating class proxies, building meta model? At least with EclipseLink there is the option to build the meta model as well as the class proxy at compile time, not at runtime. Maybe there is a similar option in Hibernate.

Comment: By the way: of course you can pool `EntityManagerFactory` instances. But be aware that you don't exhaust your resources: they may have connection pools with open connections.

Comment: @Michael: Good suggestion! I did add an update with more Information and JProfiler profiling to the original question.

Comment: @user643011 fyi, using the 'Set as root' command in JProfiler makes it way easier to filter out the noise in a big call tree stack.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to do this by implementing your own `ConnectionProvider` as a decorator around a real `ConnectionProvider`.

The key observation here is that the `ConnectionProvider` isn't used until an `EntityManager` is created (see comment in `supportsAggressiveRelease()` for a caveat to that).  So you can create a `DeferredConnectionProvider` class, and use it to construct the `EntityManagerFactory`, but then wait for user input, and do the deferred initialization before actually creating any `EntityManager` instances.  I'm written this as a wrapper around `ConnectionPoolImpl`, but you should be able to use any other implementation of `ConnectionProvider` as the base.

```
public class DeferredConnectionProvider implements ConnectionProvider {

    private Properties configuredProps;
    private ConnectionProviderImpl realConnectionProvider;

    @Override
    public void configure(Properties props) throws HibernateException {
        configuredProps = props;
    }

    public void finalConfiguration(String jdbcUrl, String userName, String password) {
        configuredProps.setProperty(Environment.URL, jdbcUrl);
        configuredProps.setProperty(Environment.USER, userName);
        configuredProps.setProperty(Environment.PASS, password);

        realConnectionProvider = new ConnectionProviderImpl();
        realConnectionProvider.configure(configuredProps);
    }

    private void assertConfigured() {
        if (realConnectionProvider == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Not configured yet!");
        }
    }        

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        assertConfigured();

        return realConnectionProvider.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void closeConnection(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        assertConfigured();

        realConnectionProvider.closeConnection(conn);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws HibernateException {
        assertConfigured();

        realConnectionProvider.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        // This gets called during EntityManagerFactory construction, but it's 
        // just a flag so you should be able to either do this, or return
        // true/false depending on the actual provider.
        return new ConnectionProviderImpl().supportsAggressiveRelease();
    }
}
```

a rough example of how to use it:

```
    // Get an EntityManagerFactory with the following property set:
    //     properties.put(Environment.CONNECTION_PROVIDER, DeferredConnectionProvider.class.getName());
    HibernateEntityManagerFactory factory = (HibernateEntityManagerFactory) entityManagerFactory;

    // ...do user input of connection info...

    SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = (SessionFactoryImpl) factory.getSessionFactory();
    DeferredConnectionProvider connectionProvider = (DeferredConnectionProvider) sessionFactory.getSettings()
                    .getConnectionProvider();

    connectionProvider.finalConfiguration(jdbcUrl, userName, password);
```

You could put the initial set up of the `EntityManagerFactory` on a separate thread or something, so that the user never has to wait for it.  Then the only thing they'll wait for, after specifying the connection info, is the setting up of the connection pool, which should be fairly quick compared to parsing the object model.

Comment: Worked nicely! Using `DeferredConnectionProvider` we setup an `EntityManagerFactoryPool`. Opening the db is sub 1 second now.

Answer (score 3):

> *Can I turn off some EntityManagerFactory features to get an instance faster?*

Don't believe so.  EMFs don't really have too many features, other than initializing a JDBC connection/pool.

> *Or is it possible to create some of the EntityManagerFactory lazily to
>   speed up cration?*

Rather than creating the EMF lazily, when the user will notice the performance hit, I suggest you should head in the opposite direction - create the EMF proactively before the user actually needs it.  Create it once, up-front, possibly in a separate thread during application initialisation (or at least as soon as you know about your database).  Reuse it throughout the existence of your application/database.

> *Can I somehow create the EntityManagerFactory object before knowing the database url?*

No - it creates a JDBC connection.

I think a better question is:  why does your application *dynamically* discover database connection URLs?  Are you saying your databases are created/made available on-the-fly and there's no way to anticipate in advance the connection parameters.  That really is to be avoided.

> *By doing so, can I pool EntityManagerFactorys for later use?*

No, you can't pool EMFs.  It's the connections that you can pool.

> *Any other idea how to create the EntityManagerFactory faster?*

I agree - 6 seconds is too slow for initialisation of EMFs.

I suspect it's more to do with your selected database technology than JPA/JDBC/JVM.  My guess is that maybe your database is initialising itself as you connect.  Are you using Access?  What DB are you using?

Are you connecting to a database remotely located?  Over a WAN? Is network speed/latency good?

Are the client PCs limited in performance?

**EDIT: Added after comments**

Implementing your own ConnectionProvider as a decorator around a real ConnectionProvider will not speed up the user's experience at all.  The database instance still needs to be initialised, the EMF & EM created and the JDBC connection still needs to be subsequently established.

Options:

1. Share a common preloaded DB instance: seems not possible for your business scenario (although JSE technology supports this and also supports client-server design).
2. Change to a DB with a faster startup: Derby (a.k.a. Java DB) is included in modern JVMs and has a startup time of about 1.5 seconds (cold) and 0.7 seconds (warm - data pre-loaded).
3. In many (most?) scenarios, the fastest solution would be to load data directly into in-memory java objects using JAXB with STAX.  Subsequently, use in-memory cached data (particularly using smart structures like maps, hashing and arraylists).  Just as JPA can map POJO classes to database tables & columns, so JAXB can map POJO classes to XML schema & work with XML doc instances.  If you have very complex queries using SQL set-based logic with multiple joins and strong use of DB indexes, this would be less desirable.

(2) would probably give the best improvement for limited effort.
Additionally: 
 - try to unzip the data files during deployment rather than during app usage.
 - initialize the EMF in a startup thread that runs in parallel to the UI startup - try to start the DB initializing as one of the very first steps of the app (that means connecting to the actual instance using JDBC).

Comment: The application reads an application format, that basicly builds on 1 SQLite database in a zip file, on local storage (no WLAN involved). We designed it, so it builds on proven technology (SQLite) and is easy to process. It is not possible to know the database url before the user openes the file. I have amended the original question with more information. Thanks for the suggestions so far!

Comment: It builds (or at least initialises from scratch) a database instance from a zip file once or multiple times for each user login session??  Well, seems that would be the majority of your 6 second wait - probably little to do with JPA.

Comment: A dynamically-initialised-client-database-instance-per-user pattern is most unusual and obviously has a startup delay.  Any reason why you couldn't share a pre-initialised common instance already loaded with necessary data?

Comment: Guys, I will reiterate this because I think I was not clear about this. It's not Java EE with a client server architecture. It's an offline desktop application that reads user files. Those application files are basicly SQLite database files plus some blobs zipped to a single file. We do initialize the database once per file open, not multiple times. There is no "session". It's a desktop application. We are already using a precreated database template for new files. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for clarification.  Have appended my post.