# JPA Entitymanagerfactory takes 3-4 seconds too long for Homepage, J2EE

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I am building a website with **J2EE on a JBoss Server** and I have a database to which I connect via **JPA.**

But this line:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceService");
```

takes about 3-4 seconds. What is the normal practice to get it faster?

I read: [Hibernate faster EntityManagerFactory creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036233/hibernate-faster-entitymanagerfactory-creation)

But it doesn't apply here, because I don't have an application, I have a website and I don't have dynamic db-urls, it's always the same.

If it would be a normal application, I would just start a thread at the beginning at initialize it before the user needs it. But it's a website, so I can't do that. If I would store it on the server and let the user call it from the front end, I guess there will be massive problems when there are too many user-requests at the same time.

This is some logging info it throws:

```
WARN HibernatePersistence:58 - HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
INFO Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO Environment:346 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
DEBUG BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@764e2837 // this line about 40 times
WARN DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:93 - HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
11:52:30,793  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:166 - HHH000401: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://...]
11:52:30,793  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:175 - HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=******, password=****}
11:52:30,793  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:180 - HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
11:52:30,795  INFO DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl:102 - HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
11:52:32,895  INFO Dialect:145 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
11:52:32,913  INFO LobCreatorBuilder:123 - HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11:52:33,116  INFO ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:47 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

From my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="PlayerService" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
```

EDIT:

Okay, I tried using

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="PlayerService") private EntityManager em;
```

But em is null when I try to use it. Do I have the right jar for

```
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

and

```
<persistence-unit name="PlayerService" transaction-type="JTA">
```

?
I have hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar.

I read something about, that I can use the @PersistenceContext(...) only in beans, but how do I declare a class as a bean?

Comment: Have you tried changing the persistence provider from org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence to org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider?

Comment: If you are creating the `EntityManagerFactory` yourself, than it's not J2EE! In a J2EE environment, it should be the containers duty to manage the `EntityManagerFactory`, and you should just inject it (or look it up from JNDI)

Comment: Okey, I hoped to have a way around it. I will change the provider to jpa. Do I need to change the transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" to "JTA"? And is this the right way: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/usclient005.htm

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is used commonly in J2SE application where you need to invoke Persistence bootstrap to obtain reference to the EntityManagerFactory and full all the cycle by yourselves, but in J2EE this approach are not used in that way.

You should consider user Container-Managed EntityManager

> When a container-managed entity manager is used, the lifecycle of the
>   persistence context is always managed automatically, transparently to
>   the application, and the persistence context is propagated with the
>   JTA transaction.
>
> A container-managed persistence context may be defined to have either
>   a lifetime that is scoped to a single transaction or an extended
>   lifetime that spans multiple transactions, depending on the
>   PersistenceContextType that is specified when its entity manager is
>   created. This specification refers to such persistence contexts as
>   transaction-scoped persistence contexts and extended persistence
>   contexts respectively.

Consider change your implementation to use this approach whit it the EntityManager can be available using @PersistenceContext and wont take more than ms to start using the EM.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="")
EntityManager em;
```

It is very simple to change to it, just add the persistence.xml to your web app in META-INF , be sure you have the jar of your provide.

> The persistence scope of the container managed entity manager is
>   Transaction by default. The transaction-type is always JTA.

To be able to work with EJB use this approach.

```
@Stateless
public class TriggerPersister {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="PlayerService") 
    private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Dont forget to have in place META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">


<!-- Add the persistence context for OrderDetail -->
<persistence-unit name="PlayerService"
    transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
            <jta-data-source>jdbc/myDs</jta-data-source>
            <class>our.class<class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

You should have a valid dataSource in the deploy folder in jboss. And the `jta-data-source` tag to indicate what will use the app

Check this link  https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Connectors_on_JBoss-Configuring_JDBC_DataSources.html

Comment: Thanks, I tried to make the change, but I failed. I edited the first post. Can you see the mistake?

Comment: Please let me know in which component are you trying to insert the entitymanager, in servlet, ejb, service or which one ?

Comment: It's in the ejb-project.

Comment: Update in my response, please provide any stackTrace to try to solve

Comment: It's still just a nullPointException on em. The @PersistenceContext does not work. I used your persistence.xml (and changed the closing class-tag to </class> and included the classpath to the class where I want to use the Context.

I have the feeling I am missing something trivial. Do I need to configure something on the JBoss? Or is my way of starting a normal main-class in Java to test the database connection wrong?

Comment: Do you have your datasource placed in jboss deploy folder,?  I forgot to add jta-datasource check my update

Comment: Looks promising, I will do that. But when I try to access the JBoss Admin Console, he wants a user, and add-user.bat works bot doesnt add it to the user file. I hope I can fix that tomoroow.